# Determine the visual size of an object at a given distance from origin (using perspective)

Tags: css, math, perspective

Let's say we have a square, 50 pixels wide. And the -webkit-perspective is `1000px*`.

What is the formula to determine how big the square will *appear* to be at a given distance from the viewer (the width it will actually appear to be on screen)?

`*` This means that the viewer's position is 1000px from the `z=0` point.

Comment: Are you assuming that the view is from the origin and the square faces it (i.e. no funny angles)?

Comment: Wait, is this 2D or 3D? And why not start with a line segment before worrying about a square? (In 3D, a square near the viewer doesn't *look* square, the sides bulge outward.)

Comment: No funny business. Assume it is a straight line from the viewport to the center of the object to the vanishing point.

Comment: So... you want to know the angular width of a square 50 pixels wide (warning: very bad units) when seen from a distance of x pixels, is that right?

Comment: Yes. If those are bad units, use whatever you'd prefer and I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular width of a square 50 units wide, when seen from a distance of x units, is `2 atan(25/x)` (in radians).

Comment: Is there any way to convert angular size into apparent linear size (in units)?

Comment: @cmal: yes, multiply it by a constant. Pick a constant that gives you a field of view you like. If the constant is too small, you'll get a fish-eye effect. If it's too large it'll be like looking through binoculars.

Comment: the "multiply it by a constant" part is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.